# Is it sufficient that if graph is bipartite and have some vertex degrees that corresponds to any grid graph is a grid?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computational-mathematics, computational-geometry

I have a graph and want to prove the sufficiency of this claim.

> Is it sufficient that if the graph is bipartite and has some vertex degrees that correspond to any grid graph is a grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is false.

To give a specific example, the $4 \times 4$ grid graph is not isomorphic to the $4 \times 4$ knight graph:

[image] [image]

However, they are both bipartite and both have the degree sequence $2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4$.

One way to distinguish the knight graph from any grid graph ($4\times 4$ or $2\times 8$ or $1\times 16$) is that the knight graph has degree-$2$ vertices adjacent to degree-$4$ vertices, which cannot happen in a grid graph.

---

But in general, we don't expect such a claim to be true, because even with a limitation like "bipartite" we expect lots and lots of realizations of most degree sequences. There's just lots and lots of graphs!

Comment: that was great !
thanks for example

Comment: Maybe I can also check that degree-2 and degree-4 vertices are not connected with each other. But that also needs a proof for this claim.

Comment: I don't expect that to work either; the number of bipartite graphs with the degree sequence of a grid graph should be much much larger than the number of grid graphs. (For that specific claim, we can also get a counterexample by surrounding the $4\times 4$ knight graph with a "frame".)

Comment: @MishaLavrov Hi, would it be possible if you can help with some graph theory problems? Like in a room chat or something? I just have many problems, and instead of posting for each on stackoverflow, and you answer regardless here, I thought you may help this way, as I checked the users and found you good at discrete mathematics,

Comment: @Papa There are certainly chat rooms that people use on this website where you can find people that will do this for you, but I prefer not to use them.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I couldn't find them, can you help with this problem: Suppose that you have 50 boys and 50 girls, and all boys have identical preferences. How many steps would the stable marriage algorithm take?